# How to handle when a Client or Server is Down in a UDP Application

Tags: c, windows, winapi, udp

I am developing a windows application for Client Server communication using UDP, but since UDP is connectionless, whenever a Client goes down, the Server does not know that Client is off and keeps sending the data. Similar is the case when a Server is down.
How can I cater this condition that whenever any of the Client or Server is down, the other party must know it and can handle it.
Waiting for reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking is beyond the scope of UDP. You'd need to implement your own protocol, over UDP, to achieve this.

One simple idea could be to periodically send [*keepalive messages*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) (TCP on the other hand has this feature).

You can have a simple implementation as follows:

- Have a background thread keep sending those messages and waiting for replies.
- Upon receiving replies, you can populate some sort of data structure
  or a file with a list of alive devices.
- Your other main thread (or threads) can have the following changes:

  1. Before sending any data, check if the client you're going to send to is present in that file/data structure.
  2. If not, skip this client.
  3. Repeat the above for all remaining clients in the populated file/data structure.

One problem I can see in the above implementation is analogous to the [RAW hazard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28computer_architecture%29#Read_After_Write_.28RAW.29) from the main thread's perspective.

Use the following analogy instead of the [mentioned example for the RAW hazard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28computer_architecture%29#Example),

- `i1` = Your background thread which sends the keepalive messages.
- `i2` = Your main thread (or threads) which send/receive data and do your other tasks.
- The RAW hazard here would be when `i2` tries to read the data structure/file which is populated by `i1` **before** `i1` has updated it.
- This means (worst case), `i2` will not get the updated list and it can miss out a few clients this way.
- If this loss would be critical, I can suggest that you possibly have a sort of mechanism whereby `i1` will signal `i2` when it completes any-ongoing writing.
- If this loss is not critical, then you can skip the above mechanism to make your program faster.

---

### Explanation for Keepalive Messages:

You just need to send a very lightweight message (usually has no data. Just the header information). **Make sure** this message **is unique**. You *do not* want another message being interpreted as a keepalive message.

You can send this message using a `sendto()` call to a [broadcast address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address#IP_networking). After you finish sending, wait for replies for a certain timeout using `recv()`.

Log every reply in a data structure/file. After the timeout expires, have the thread go to sleep for some time. When that time expires, repeat the above process.

To help you get started writing good, robust networking code, please go through [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html). It is absolutely wonderful. It explains many concepts.

Comment: A common solution is to open a second TCP connection to detect dropped connections, as well as sending any critical messages. This is based on the assumption that it is very rare for the TCP connection to stay up but the UDP connection to fail, given the two endpoints are the same.

Comment: @CongXu, Yes you are correct. But, if the TCP connection was to be used, it can be used to send the data itself (because TCP has this detection). Maybe only for critical data, like you said.

Comment: @AnishRam : That was very helpful :) can you give me an example for that?

Comment: I am not allowed to use TCP in any condition, I have to stick to UDP only :(

Comment: @AnishRam Aren't we already working under the assumption that we want to use UDP and not TCP, for whatever reason? :) For a real example of what I'm talking about, check out [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) which is used to stream media but also allow VCR-like commands. RTP (over UDP) is used for the actual data transmission, TCP is used for the VCR-like commands (pause/play, ff, rew).

Comment: @CongXu, My bad. Your example looks quite interesting to be sure.

Comment: @AyeshaHassan, Can you be a little more specific? An example for what?

Comment: @AnishRam : I need a sample code for both Server and Client showing the implementation of KeepAlive in UDP :(
I am little confused, do I need to send the ACK from Client ( using sendto() ) in reply to KeepAlive messages from Server or the Operating system will do it from Client side?

Comment: I searched internet alot and found out that SO_KEEPALIVE is only for TCP Sockets. Anyone help me with this please? :(

Comment: @AyeshaHassan, So what do you do when you need something and it doesn't exist? Invent it of course! I've edited my answer to explain what I meant about keepalive messages. As for sample code, please go through [the link I mentioned in my answer](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) to help you get started. It clearly explains several concepts.